# How to manage google service accounts from helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am in the learning phase of kubernetes and able to set up deployments, services etc. However I have got stuck on how to manage secrets.

Context

1. I am using GKE for Kubernetes cluster
2. I am using helm charts for managing all deployment operations
3. I have created a google service account that has access to say google cloud storage.

My application uses the helm to create deployments and services, however, how do I manage the google service account creds I have created in an automated way like

1. I do not want to create the secrets manually like this - `kubectl create secret generic pubsub-key --from-file=key.json=PATH-TO-KEY-FILE.json` ,
   I want to do it through helm because say tomorrow if I move to another k8s cluster then I have do it manually again
2. Is there anyway to push my helm charts to repos without concerning of exposing my secrets as plain objects.

Apart from this, any other guidelines and best practices would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Harsh for the answer. I have made it work in little different way like this

1. I want my creds to be in helm values files
2. I want to commit my helm values to the git so that I can use the GITOPS at its full potential
3. I want to use just helm for deployment without manual intervention during CI CD process

So this is what I did

1. I have made use of helm AES and DES functions.
2. I encrypt the fields in values fields with AES function and commit it to the GIT
3. When installing the chart, I use `--set aesKey=myEncryptedKey` with `helm install` command.

Here is how it goes

1. I have `google-service-account-creds.json`, I create the base64 of the json present in this file
2. In values.yaml i chose a field say `encrypt_account_info` = `base64 data from above`
3. I encrypt the above field with AES
4. Now I was able to commit it to git as it my secret is encrypted.
5. In service.yaml, I have use `google-cloud-service-account: {{ .Values.encrypt_account_info | decryptAES (.Values.aesKey | b64dec) }}`
6. While installing the secret i use the following command `helm install google-account-cred-release google-account-service/ --set aesKey=mykey1`

**Values file** ( It is my encrypted google service account credentials usin AES method )

```
encrypt_account_info: 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
```

**Secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: google-cloud-service-account
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  google-cloud-service-account: {{ .Values.encrypt_account_info | decryptAES (.Values.aesKey | b64dec) }}
```

command to install

```
helm install google-service-account-release google-service --set aesKey=myykey
```

It is all inspired by this - https://itnext.io/helm-3-secrets-management-4f23041f05c3

Comment: So the Key you are passing `aesKey=mykey1` won't get committed to Git right ? this looks quite promising and a good approach.

Comment: Yes, right it will not be commited to git .. this will be present only in CI CD framework like jenkins ..

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to create the secrets manually like this - kubectl
> create secret generic pubsub-key
> --from-file=key.json=PATH-TO-KEY-FILE.json , I want to do it through helm because say tomorrow if I move to another k8s cluster then I have
> do it manually again

You can create the **secret** template to helm which will create the secret for you, at run time of helm time.

You helm will find the `service account.json` and create the secret based on that.

For example **service-account.yaml**

```
{{- $all := . -}}
{{ range $name, $secret := .Values.serviceAccountSecrets }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ $name }}
    chart: {{ template "atlantis.chart" $all }}
    component: service-account-secret
    heritage: {{ $all.Release.Service }}
    release: {{ $all.Release.Name }}
data:
  service-account.json: {{ $secret }}
---
{{ end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
serviceAccountSecrets:
  # credentials: <json file as base64 encoded string>
  # credentials-staging: <json file as base64 encoded string>
```

Or else you can use this GCP service account controller which creates the **Serviceaccount** and the **secret** for you.

https://github.com/kiwigrid/gcp-serviceaccount-controller

> Is there anyway to push my helm charts to repos without concerning of
> exposing my secrets as plain objects.

For committing issues you can use the `.helmignore` file.

Read more at : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/helm_ignore_file/

So inside the GIT, you have to commit only `values.yaml` not `values-dev.yaml`, `values-stag.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not understand how values-dev.yaml and value-stag.yaml are generated ? Not clear from the answer above

Comment: you can keepe this fille with differentt configuration which will be there copy of vaues.yaml and have just the different configuration.

Comment: Those files are created manually. It's the data you feed to helm when it should install a release.

Answer (score 0):

Secret management is a complex topic, and there are many approaches possible, like using the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) in GCP.

However, for the specific problem of managing Google Service Account credentials in GKE, the recommended approach is to use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

This way, you don't even have to create keys. You have to activate Workload Identity and create mappings for the Kubernetes service account to the GCP service account. Once this is set up, you can just set the Deployment's Kubernetes service account to that account using Workload Identity.